# Using one string variable's value in another variable is converting all special characters in hex code

Tags: karate

My string variable is `* string variable1 = '&config=1'`.When i am using this variable into another variable then `&` and `=` is converted to hex code `%26config%3D1`

Comment: @peter can you please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you used these in the URL, of course then this will be URL-encoded and this is the correct behavior.

See link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Also please use the `param` keyword for query-string parameters:

```
And param config = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @peter but i have a doubt.Lets say my api accepts params ```config=1-0&config=2-0``` then how can i pass two same param.When i am passing two same params then last param override first one.

Comment: @GauravKinra try: `And param config = ['1-0', '2-0']

Comment: Thanks a lot @peter